# Black effect when screen popping controller with custom animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cabasicanimation

I am popping a view controller from navigation controller.When i am popping controller i want to give it animation like Pushing a view controller.For that purpose i am using below code

```
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3f;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                forKey:kCATransition];

    [self.appDelegate setUpForLVC];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

When animation starts i get black effect here.Please tell me what is the issue with my code ?

Comment: set clearcolor in window

Comment: How to set please alter the code

Answer (score 4):

add this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


      **OR**
2)Set animation duration to 0
```