# Screen goes black after pop controller with custom animation

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to push controller with animation of like presenting controller and poping the controller like dismiss.

I am using this code for pushing the controller

```
    let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.4
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
    transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
    AppDelegate.shared.window?.rootViewController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.push(articleDetailScene, animated: false)
```

And for pop using this code.

```
    let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.0
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut)
    transition.type = CATransitionType.reveal
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromBottom
    self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.pop(animated: false)
```

After posing the controller , a black screen appears at the bottom of screen. I have used this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272209/black-effect-when-screen-popping-controller-with-custom-animation) but that creates a white screen for that space and not showing my cells at that space.
[Black screen when I don't use window background color to white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUDXj.png) and [When I set window background color to white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFP14.png).

Comment: How you set the frame of pushed view controller? I think the issue is not related to the transition code.

Comment: You probably don't keep a reference on the view controller that you are about to present and the garbage collector clears the presented view items. Try keep one

Comment: There is no garbage collector in swift lol

Comment: I tried but it's issue because of transition code as when I set animated to true it's not showing black screen

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sample code.

I am adding to transition to self.view's window instead of AppDelegate's  window

I have base view controller and have following method there

```
func addTransitionForPush () {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.55
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromBottom
    transition.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
}


func addTransitionForPop () {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.55
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
    transition.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.backwards
    view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
}
```

How I use this in my view controller

For Pushing VC

```
@objc private func btnFilterTapped() {
    self.addTransitionForPush()
    let vc = self.storyboard........
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```

For Poping

```
    self.addTransitionForPop()
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

Please let me know If you still facing black screen issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is still showing black screen at the bottom as mentioned.

Comment: @vikashkumar Did you try exactly what mentioned in answer ?

Comment: Yes @Prashant, I didn't work for me. Black screen still showing after controller gets pop and when I change the tab then black screen goes away.

Comment: @vikashkumar I have also tabbar controller things working perfectly for me. You can create a sample project with tabbar  and try the same thing there. And see you are getting black screen or not with that you might identity your problem in your project

Comment: The problem is that when I set animated to true, it's working fine but that also shows animation of like poping from right but when I set animated to false animation is as per my requirement but still creates black screen.